# I want to use list comprehension for this code in python

Tags: python

I have two lists lst and count I need enumerate on lst and check if lst elements exists in count or not if not then append it in another list else pass.

```
for i, u in enumerate(lst ):
    if u in count:
        pass
    else:
        _ = sku[i].pop("_id")
        objects.append(sku[i])
```

```
I need this code to be in one line
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: `_ = sku[i].pop("_id")` could be `del sku[i]["_id"]`, avoiding unused var.  A one-liner may be possible but I don't think you can use a comprehension for this.  Does `objects` start out empty i.e. this code is generating it, or is this appending to existing content?

Comment: Why do you "need" this in one line?

Answer (score 1):

What's the content of `lst`, `count`, `sku` and `objects` before this code?

If I assume that these data are: list, list, list of dicts and empty list, you can maybe do something like this:

```py
objects = [{k: v for k, v in sku[i].items() if k != i} for i, u in enumerate(lst) if u not in count]
```

It's one line, but it's not readable nor understandable!

**I don't recommend you using one-line or comprehension list for such complex method.**